# $f'(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ with $\deg f < p$ implies $f(x) \equiv c \pmod{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $f(x) = P(x)/Q(x)$ where $P, Q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Define $\deg f = \max(\deg P, \deg Q)$. Then as usual, $f'(x) = (Q(x)P'(x) - P(x)Q'(x))/Q(x)^2$.

Suppose for some prime $p$, we had $f'(n) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ for all $n$ and $\deg f = \max(\deg P, \deg Q) < p$. Why must $f(n) \equiv c \pmod{p}$ for some $c$?

Note: This a major revision of the previous (poorly stated/understood) question I asked.

Comment: @user26857: It turns out I was misinterpreting what I was reading, I have changed to question to better reflect what I want to ask.

Comment: @barto: It turns out that that's not how I define $\deg f$. I define it as $\max(\deg g, \deg h)$, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{a_kx^k}$$
with $0\leq a_k<p$ and at least one $a_k\neq 0$. Then
$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{(k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k}}$$
If $f'(x)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, this means that each element $(k+1)a_{k+1}$ is $0$ for $0\leq k\leq n-1$. If $n<p$, so that $n-1<p-1$, then $0<k+1<p$, so if $(k+1)a_{k+1}=0$ then $a_{k+1}=0$. Thus if the polynomial is identically $0$ and $n<p$ we must have that $a_k=0$ for all $k>0$, so $f$ is constant. This settles the question for polynomials.

Suppose now that $h$ is a rational function with $h(x)=f(x)/g(x)$ and $f$ and $g$ relatively prime. Then
$$h'(x)=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}$$
If this is identically $0$, then
$$f'(x)g(x)=f(x)g'(x)$$
Since $f$ and $g$ are relatively prime and $g(x)|f(x)g'(x)$, this means that $g(x)|g'(x)$. Since $\deg(g'(x))<\deg(g(x))$, this means that $g'(x)=0$, so $g(x)$ must be constant, so that $g(x)=c$ for some $c$. Thus
$$cf'(x)=0$$
so that
$$f'(x)=0$$
Since $\deg(h)<p$, this means $\deg(f)<p$. Thus $f$ must be constant as well, so $h$ is constant.

Comment: $f$ is a rational function, not necessarily a polynomial.

Comment: @barto Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @user26857: Implicitly throughout, we're viewing $f$ and $g$ now as functions over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. So we have $f'(x)g(x) = f(x)g'(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_{p}$. If one really wanted to be pedantic, I suppose one could add the phrase "over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$" everywhere, but I definitely agree that Matt's solution is correct.